# Why nothing happen when I run the git bash command: "lt --port 3000" using localtunnel?

Tags: node.js, facebook, git-bash, localtunnel

I'm looking to develop a facebook messenger app and it requires to implement a localtunnel with nodeJS.
So I installed node (v 13.9.0), npm (v 6.13.7) and localtunnel package on Git Bash (because I'm on windows 10).

However when I try to get a localtunnel adresse using Git bash command "lt --port 3000" the Git bash terminal is running but he doesn't give me any web adress that I can use.

I looked at the github repository issue and they advice to enter the bash command: "lt -h "http://serverless.social" -p 3000". However I have a new error: 504 Gateway Time. Here I'm stuck ...

Thanks for any advice ! :)

**EDIT:** The project seems to have global issue on Github where you can look at here https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues

Comment: I know this thread is quite old but Were you able to find the answer for this? I am facing the same issue now.

Answer (score -1):

You should first install `localtunnel`:

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

Then,

```
lt --port 3000
```

or You can just type:

```
npx localtunnel --port 3000
```